# Cinderblock cmu masonry question

Tags: walls, basement, masonry, cinderblock

I'm replacing a 7ft. Basement Wall with 10" block. We tried to demo carefully as to save some interlocking blocks in the corners. A few broke resulting in a few cuts having to be made.
My question is, when dealing with a cut which ends up going through one of the two cores in the block, should the cut side face the existing wall butting up to it, or should the cut piece face towards the new wall being put up?
Thanks.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make a difference. Either way is fine, just make sure the cut is even so the mortar joint is even.

If you're concerned about it being weakened, fill the core with grout after the block is in place.

Comment: That's what I thought. Yes, being it's the corner. I was doing vertical rebar and grout.